# aborted linux installation and now I can't access my hard-disk

Tags: linux, installation

I aborted the linux ubuntu installation and now I can't access my hard-disk, is there a way i can use it without having to format it? I have a lot of photos there and would not want to lose them.

Comment: anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a bootable disk to access the system, copy the data on to an external drive, then reinstall, although as dmb stated it's conceivable that the bootloader has been overwritten and just needs fixing.

If your data is not visible, you may be able to retrieve some of it using Testdisk and/or photorec - but more specific advice can't be given without knowing exactly what has happened.

Comment: I used Testdisk and it said the hard disk's type is VFM or something like that, and it had Linux before it, does it mean it completely finished formatting it?

Comment: Its important to know exactly what it is - If it is LVM and was Linux, that means that the partition type has changed for a partition (which is not the same as the entire drive).  Its likely that your drive is scrambled, but its conceivable that testdisk can fix it (but it requires some knowledge and scanning the whole thing for backup EXT4 superblocks). If not, testdisk may be able to recover some of your photos - although recovering from a backup would be an easier option if thats open to you.

Comment: I was using the server version, ill try another version to try it and hope i can recover my files

Comment: If that wont work ill let you know

Comment: used photorec, thanks for your help! I recovered the files

Answer (score 0):

With the information you gave, I can assume that you installed Linux and whatever other os in the same drive. So the grub partition, must have gotteng messed up. Your chance here is boot on a live system, install Grub and refresh. I might add, that you should backup everything important on the partition and fresh install everything.

For future installations, you should install linux in a different partition to the other OS. This is because grub, gets intalled in that drive(usually as the first partition) so when it gets deleted there is nothing to boot. So if you have the other OS in another drive, you only need to put that drive in the first place in the booting order and that's that.

Cheers.

Comment: unfortunately it seems like i didn't install the os :/

Comment: @frenchdood then check if you can mount the drive on a live distro. This drive you are talking about, did it use to have a os?

Comment: it did not use to have an os